# Java или Python?

Tags: python, java

По производительности в разных источниках пишут разное, в одних что Python в десятки раз медленнее, по другим источникам одного порядка. Вообще какие минусы есть у них относительно друг друга? В Python как я понял больше разных фишек, но смущает динамическая типизация, кажется это неудобно(никогда не использовал). Вобщем сбор мнений)

Comment: наверное, вы имели ввиду не сам язык, а существующие компиляторы и интерпритаторы))

Comment: Вот аналогичный вопрос на SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559618/about-speed-python-vs-java

Comment: И вообще, откуда такой вопрос? Не могу себе представить, чтобы где-то был вопрос выбора между ними. Всё зависит от задачи. Задача и определяет ответ на этот вопрос вполне однозначно.

Comment: а главное давайте подумаем почему и зачем язык сделали строго-динамической типизации? и сравним с тем что я написал выше и что вызвало бурю эмоций?

Answer (score 8):

Язык сам по себе не имеет такой характеристики как скорость исполнения. Важны средства времени  исполнения.

- CPython интерпретируется и обычно медленнее, чем Java, особенно если в Java используется JIT-компиляция;
- JYthon интерпретируется в JVM и по скорости не отличается от Java;
- Cython компилируется в машинный код и по скорости превосходит Java.

Comment: в добавок: при JIT-компиляции код компилируется во время работы программы, когда он будет востребован, затем он кешируется и используется при следующей необходимости, поэтому первое нажатие на кнопку выполняется чуть-чуть дольше, чем последующие.

Comment: А вот про третюю точку поподробнее.. Я ни разу не видел, чтобы питон где-то был быстрее явы кроме тестов длиной менее 300 мс

Comment: Cython, судя по тому, что мельком видел - это не питон (средство для написания с-расширений для питона). Сомнения вызывает 2 строка - jython (в прошлом веке jpython). Не знаю, как сейчас, но раньше питон с numeric обгонял java на вычислениях, т.к. достаточно тяжёлые функции библиотеки написаны на c. Ну и вопрос статической типизации в java достаточно тонкий за счёт оо-наследований.

Answer (score 5):

1. Считать производительность нужно не в разах, а в "приемлимо/неприемлимо"
2. Девиз развития языков программирования и методик начиная с 50ых: **Как уменьшить время разработки/изменения программ, при сохранении приемлимых скорости выполнения программ и потребления памяти**. Универсального рецепта до сих пор нет, потому что с одной стороны железо так и не стало обладать бесконечными быстродействием и размером памяти, а с другой - при увеличении сложности программы (и как следствии - увеличении количества разработчиков) выявились сложности для обеспечения приемлимого качества разработки.
3. Динамическая типизация призвана (и увеличивает) скорость разработки. За счет - снижения эффективности выполнения программы. И при увеличении размера программы и количества разработчиков - меры по обеспечению приемлимого качества разработки могут в итоге уравнять общую скорость разработки (*утрировано - пишем на Python'е как будто на Java и разводим бюрократию процесса согласования и проч*).

Минусы-плюсы в итоге - это одни и те же качества ЯП.

Например вот так:

Java:

Минус - статическая типизация

Плюс - статическая типизация

Python:

Минус - динамическая типизация

Плюс - динамическая типизация

Вот такие *минусы есть у них относительно друг друга*

Comment: Как-то всё сразу стало непонятно. Даже то, что вроде-бы было более-менее понятно. И почему динамическая типизация именно призвана увеличивать скорость разработки. Совсем не факт. (Ну, а как складывать минусы-плюсы, так вообще - туман). И причём тут бюрократия процесса? Т.е. о том, что при забюрократизированном процессе использование ООП не приводит к серьёзным увеличениям накладных расходов, я читал. Но сравнение java-python тут каким боком?

Comment: 1. Скорость разработки, особенно простых приложений - еще какой факт, проверенный уже поколениями программистов. Мало того, от обратного - если бы не было фактом - популярных ЯП с динамической типизацией вообще бы не было. 2. Складывание же плюсов и минусов ложки и молотка - да, дело изначально туманное. Недостатки - это продолжение достоинств или "за все нужно платить". 3. ООП - вообше ни при чем к тому что сказал. 4. "Java или Python" - кардинальное отличие между ними - в виде типизации. Остальное - следствия. Если бы "Java или C#" или "Ruby или Python" то и ответ был бы другим.

Comment: у а если обратить внимание на чистоту статичности (приведение типов в java наследник->предок->наследок)? 
И, кстати, жизнь тут поставила интересный эксперимент. Сколько было библиотек всяких контейнерных классов ранее, и сколько их осталось после введения в язык шаблонов. :) А ООП был упомянут исключительно из-за непонятной ссылки на бюрократизацию. И ещё, серьёзные отличия между java и python - не только типизация. Одно из других - функциональные возможности змея. Ну и ещё можно посмотреть слайды Норвига о шаблонах проектирования в динамических языках.

Answer (score 2):

Если брать в чистом виде, то,

Плюсы джава:

1. выполнение джавовского байт-кода на порядки шустрее питоновского интерпретатора.
2. статическая типизация в джаве способствует отлову множества ошибок на этапе компиляции.
3. ООП в джаве очень хорошо проработан, по сравнению с довольно странной реализацией классов в питоне.
4. неслабые возможности отладки в современных ИДЕ, заточенных под джаву (netbeans, eclipse, IDEA).

Плюсы питона:

1. скриптовый язык не требует компиляции, следовательно просмотреть результат можно мгновенно после внесения изменений.
2. куча приятных плюшек в плане синтаксиса, типа срезов массива и прочих фич по работе с коллекциями.

Итого. В каждом конкретном случае решает вопрос совокупность преимуществ, либо даже наличие всего одного преимущества. Зачастую мало меняющаяся и требовательная к скорости выполнения часть проекта крутится на джаве. а часто изменяемые компоненты делаются на питоне. Похожий подход кстати нередко применяют в игрушках: основу и графику пишут на С++, а игровую логику - на Python, Lua.

PS. Согласен на счет C# - шикарный потомок сишки + отличная ИДЕ. Но имеет массу недостатков как любой продукт МС. Платформозависим, изрядно дорог, перспективы зависят только от политики МС. Не-програмные недостатки т.с. :)

Comment: java:
1. Потерю производительности в змеином интерпретаторе можно объяснить только непроходимой тупостью змееводов. Не верю. :)
2. Обсуждается рядом.
3. Странный и неубедительный аргумент (о лучшей проработанности Орг. Освоб. Палестины)
4. В питоне средства отладки (за счёт интерпретации) весьма и весьма (кстати в перечисленных инструментах есть возможность отлаживать код на питоне?)
python:
2. наверное это всё-таки не "плюшечки синтаксиса" :)))
C# - довольно странные характеристики (да и стандарты вроде есть не от ms)

Comment: alexlz, учите ассемблер, а не занимайтесь верованиями. Нужно знать во что превращается вызов метода в Java и Python'е во время выполнения, - тогда и поймете - почему любая динамика тормозней статики.

Плюсы же питона не раскрыты, там не просто плюшки, а переопределение операторов, множественное наследование, метаклассы, лямбды, менеджеры контекста, декораторы, и пр. По возможностям языка Python нужно сравнивать с Haskell или Scala, а не с Java.

Вобщем картина типическая, большинство молодых программистов знают в лучшем один язык, и берутся рассуждать о весьма другом языке и реализациях.

Comment: Ежели не секрет, какой ассемблер следует изучить, чтобы понять вышеуказанное? "Автокод БМ-4/220" подойдёт? А по возможностям (не по изобразительным свойствам) разные языки примерно равны, ибо одну и ту же задачу (теоретически) можно решить на очень многих языках (те, на которых нельзя - оставим за скобками, не о них речь)

Comment: alexlz, ассемблер - любой. Вопрос говорит о том что не знаете никакого. 2. Написать да, все можно в машинных кодах. Раз задаете вопрос о существовании языков программирования поверх машинных кодов, не разобрались и в этом вопросе.

Comment: Молодец! Ok я уже поставил поставил. (Но всё же, чем не устраивает ассемблер для 8051?)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте решите пару простеньких задачек, сначала на одном языке, потом на другом. Приходится использоваться оба языка одновременно, один для более трудоемких задач, другой для всякой мелочевки, типа парсинга логов :-)

Answer (score 1):

Одно из основных достоинств питона в том, что он имеет безумное количество всяких расширений. Внешние библиотеки numpy и scipy реализуют тяжелую математику, а все управляющие конструкции на python. В результате получается симбиоз скорости исполнения и красоты кода. С другой стороны, java  привязана к железу, должн стоять только JVM

Comment: Ага, а питон не привязан к железу, там не должна стоять CPython VM? И кол-вом библиотек Java вполне заткнёт за пояс Python.

Comment: Да уж, по количеству библиотек не с джавой тягаться :). У питона неоспоримое преимущество в скорости написания (по оценка - от 2 раз до 10 vs java). Соответственно в критичных по времени приложениях - питон может использоваться для написания прототипов, тестов и изучения java :))). Ну и jython - спасение java в 21 веке (цитата с www.jython.org

Answer (score 1):

Всегда писал на C и Shell. Сейчас изучаю java (работа попалась) по Гослингу. Почему-то не нравится, особенно потоки. И вообще, слишком много абстракции, сразу не очевидно (видимо из-за кучи наследований и переопределений методов) как это будет работать. Такое впечатление, что главное не эффективно решить задачу, а создать непонятно для кого набор универсальных инструментов, чтобы потом из них делать новые инструменты и т.д.

Comment: Вот как раз потоки-то и сделаны мега-офигенно, особенно, по сравнению с нативным барахлом ;) Просто с потоками надо уметь работать и по этой теме отдельно пишут целые книги. По поводу абстракции: почитайте классические книжки про архитектуре приложений и тогда вы поймёте для чего нужны классы и абстракции. И ещё совет - не доверяйте Гослингу. Гослинг - искусственно раскрученный персонаж.

Comment: "Мега-офигенно" - это из статьи Хансена "JAVA'S INSECURE PARALLELISM"? http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.96.9056&rep=rep1&type=pdf

А насчёт абстракций в ООП - это к специалистам. www.dreamsongs.com/Files/PatternsOfSoftware.pdf. С абстракциями там надо поаккуратнее...

Comment: Ну вы бы ещё за 65й год нашли бы источник. Знаете сколько воды утекло за 12 лет? Даже в яве за эти годы очень многое изменилось.

Comment: Да, но игнорировать четвертьвековой опыт работ по проблеме это разработчикам джавы не помешало :). И, кстати, многое - это что, если по-конкретней (исключительно из любопытства - честно).

Comment: To @cy6erGn0m. Если можно поподробнее про сравнение с "нативным барахлом". Не подумайте, что я цепляюсь, правда интересно. И почему по поводу работы с простой по сути вещью (параллельные последовательности команд, общая память, блокировки) отдельно пишут целые книги?

Comment: avp, веками люди едят хлеб, но почему-то пекарем в секунду не станешь. Параллельный поток выполнения никогда не были простым делом. И все исследования в computer science говорят о том что пока и не будет. Или дорого платить другими вещами из области "чистого функционального программирования"

Comment: Да, параллельные программы в общем случае (особенно с общей памятью) на порядок сложнее линейных. В Java, мне пока кажется, совсем заморочено. Правда обработка асинхронных событий в последовательной программе тоже СОВСЕМ НЕ ПОДАРОК. Поэтому хочется сказать - каждому процессу свой процессор (что бы ни с кем не делить) + гибкая система межпроцессорных сообщений. Кстати, локальная ОС такого процессора кардинально упрощается.

Answer (score 1):

Пользую оба, просто для разных целей.
Как писалось выше, Ява как основа аппликации, разные "вкусные" модули на питоне.
Например - пишем для нужд аппликации EvaluationEngine
Интерфейс, фабрику и структуру контекста задаем на джаве - тут все строго и меняться не будет
Реализацию пишем на питоне, все очень просто из-за человеческого синтаксиса
И самое вкусное - на питоне же можно создавать т.н. named rules - внешние по отношению к вашей программе функции, которые потом можно использовать во runtime БЕЗ перекомпиляции всего проекта.
Заказчик аж пищит - любой каприз за 5 минут (и ваши деньги)

Answer (score -1):

1 - Динамическая типизиция - невероятное зло. Поймёшь после того как подебажишь присвоение строки к инту которое падает один раз из десяти.

2 - Скорость выполнения твоей программы как ни странно сейчас мало кого сейчас волнует, если она укладывается в разумные рамки.

3 - C# лучше :) Строгая типизация + плюшечки

Comment: 1 - Неправда.

Comment: правда правда. динамическая типизация отводит проверку типов этапу выполнения а не к этапу компиляции. Ошибки компиляции чинить в разы проще чем ClassCastException.

Comment: to Эндрю Фролов:
1. Насчёт невероятного зла - понравилось. Долой жабу, с++, c# и всё объедко-ориентированное программирование (возражения принимаются только с расшифровкой термина RTTI). 
2. Т.е. разумные рамки всё-таки имеют место быть?
3. "Лучше, чем грузины" ? (Кстати, питон там тоже есть. И даже железный)

Comment: Неправда. Несоответские типов -- довольно таки типичная ошибка и обычно быстро исправляется в процессе тестирования. Мелочь.

Comment: Перегибов не надо. Тестирование (при приемлемой стоимости) далеко не все ошибки отлавливает. А ежели ошибка проявляется при эксплуатации - это не есть gut. Так что без крайностей, пожалуйста.
На ситуацию серьёзное влияние оказывают сложность проекта и квалификация разработчиков. Лично я предпочитаю статическую типизацию, но не считаю динамическую "невероятным злом".
(И, кстати, у многих ли кодеров выполняется правило: "ни одного варнинга при компиляции"?)

Comment: 1 - не понял как связана динамическая типизация и RTTI. в строго типизированных языках ты не можешь присвоить инту массив, или по крайней мере не сможешь сделать этого незаметно для себя. В этом весьм мой поинт.
2 - само собой :)
3 - ну каков пост такой и ответ :)

p.s. у меня ни одного ворнинга при копиляции. :) у нас это корпоративный стандарт.

Comment: Ответ на рекламное (про фирму) :) сообщение:но ты можешь присвоить указателю (в java этот термин не используется) на объект ссылку на объект-потомок (upcasting кажись). А затем обратно (downcasting). И всё нормально. И если напутал - положил в клетку для животных крокодила, а потом, ожидая собачку, его достал - то это проблемы рантайма. И в той же джаве динамическая проверка типов - самый главный тормоз. И сравни типизацию языках-братьях ocaml и F#. А насколько строже типизация в ocaml без возможностей .net .

Comment: Нифига не понял. Есть класс А есть класс Б наследованный от А. Сделал ты указатель на А, а положил в него Б. Когда ты захочешь из этого указателя взять Б, то ты должен будешь сделать cast явно. Тут всё подпёрто. Про F# и окамл ничего сказать не могу. видел их только на картинке, зато могу сказать про java. главный тормоз в ней - отсутсвие структур, т.е. всё сложнее простого типа лежит в хипе. из-за этого сполошные cash miss-ы :( А про проверку типов, я где-то слышал что она в яве заоптимизированно по самое не могу. ты наверное спутал с рефлекшном - вот где настоящий тормоз :)

Comment: А "cast явно" - это уже сугубо статическая типизация? И насчёт "заоптимизировано по самое немогу" - сама оптимизированная проверка  всё равно дольше, чем её отсутствие :)

Comment: "А "cast явно" - это уже сугубо статическая типизация?"- да. по определению. 

"сама оптимизированная проверка всё равно дольше, чем её отсутствие" - спасибо капитан очевидность. ну тратишь ты пару тиков процессора на чек типов и что с того?

Comment: 1. "По определению" - хм. Хотелось бы видеть такое определение. В одном модуле помещаем объект в контейнер (а в джаве у всёх есть общий предок), в другом - выбираем, и что может сделать компилятор?
Только умыть руки. 2. Пара тиков - это буквально? Или тиков всё-таки больше?